# Convert a String to w3c.dom.Element: XMLParseException:Start of root element expected

Tags: java, xml

I found the following piece of code from a blog, when running it I get an exception

> XMLParseException:Start of root element expected. at 9th line.

Can any one explain why I get the Exception and suggest any other way for converting String to an element?

```
String s = "Hello DOM Parser";
java.io.InputStream sbis = new java.io.StringBufferInputStream(s);
javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory b = javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
b.setNamespaceAware(false);
org.w3c.dom.Document doc = null;
javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder db = null;
db = b.newDocumentBuilder();
doc = db.parse(sbis);     

org.w3c.dom.Element e = doc.getDocumentElement();
```

Comment: `"Hello DOM Parser"` isn't XML.

Comment: @skaffman - there is a chance, that the original text *contained* element tags but that those tags have been eliminated through a process of copy/pasting the text between web applications... but anyway, the original post as I can see, didn't contain tag elements in the `String s` declaration.

Comment: @Abhishek, I assume you have referred my blog post based on the code snippet and the exception thrown as the string is not actually a representation of a xml element. After seeing this, I updated [my blog post](http://ddweerasiri.blogspot.com/2009/03/how-to-convert-javalangstring-to.html) to avoid any complications.

Answer (score 1):

Like said in the comment, "Hello DOM Parser" is not a XML element. And so the parser doesn't know what to do with it. I don't know what kind document you are building, but if you want HTML you can embed the text in a html tag for example;

```
<div>Hello DOM Parser</div>
<span>Hello DOM Parser</span>
```

if you are building XML, you can embed the text in any random html tag;

```
<mytag>Hello DOM Parser</mytag>
```

Some explanation on DOM;
http://www.w3.org/DOM

To answer your question, to convert a String to a w3c Element, you can use createElement;

```
Element hello = document.createElement("hello");          
hello.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Hello DOM Parser"));
```

This results in;

```
<hello>Hello DOM Parser</hello>
```

Comment: yes you are right. but agenda is how to covert string to Element

Answer (score 1):

To create a DOM `Element` with a custom tag (which I assume is what you want, but can't be sure), you can use the following approach:

```
String customTag = "HelloDOMParser";

Document doc = documentBuilder.newDocument();       

String fullName = nameSpacePrefix + ":" + customTag;

Element customElement = document.createElementNS(namespaceUri, fullName);

doc.appendChild(customElement);
```

I am assuming you know the namespace URI and your prefix (if any). If you don't use namespaces, just use the `createElement()` method instead.

Answer (score 0):

The parse method of DocumentBuilder accept the input stream which contains the xml content. The following change will work for you:

```
String s = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<root><elem1>Java</elem1></root>";
```

Try to avoid using the deprecated classes such as StringBufferInputStream. You can refer to the document below to know more about Java XML parsing.

http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=152